# Top user email without being tracked

Tags: support, reputation, top-users

I got an email telling me I'm one of the top new users (on Writers).  But I'm not in the list... of course not, since I only have 131 reputation so far.  But... how can I then be a top new user if the system doesn't track me (or at least the site claims it doesn't)?

Edit: I'm just wondering (so -bug +support) why I get the "you are in the top" email when I'm not *really* in the top since I'm not (yet) tracked in the leagues.  Or maybe that should be considered a bug, since I'm probably not the only one following the link in the email and being surprized of not finding myself when the email says I should be there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "track"?

Comment: "users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "top new user" e-mails* are actually distinct from the [StackExchange.com leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues).

The major distinction is that only **new** users can get those e-mails.  Your account on Writers is 6 days old, so you were eligible for the weekly e-mail.  You'll always be eligible to appear in the [week league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/68/week/writers), regardless of whether you've been in it before.

The idea behind the new user e-mails is to send some recognition of the merit of exemplary new users.  We also log this achievement, though I don't believe we display it anywhere at the moment.

<sub>*There are actually two kinds, weekly and monthly.  Being in either group opts you out of the other, so you don't get a "double good job."  We respect the "no e-mails, please" user setting for all of this as well.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You are actually on the top of the league *for new users*.

That is, **of all new users on that site in that given week**, you generated the most reputation.

(yes, it is a bummer that the rep leagues don't show any user with < 200 reputation, but that shouldn't detract from your achievement.)